# To calculate days in a month

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

i have a textbox that displays date in format,for eg:March,20,2008.Then i need to get total days n march in year 2008.Can anybody help

Answer (score 9):

You can use the DaysInMonth function

e.g.

```
Date.DaysInMonth(2008, 3)
```

Obviously, you'll have to pass the year and month to the function

Answer (score 5):

```
int year = DateTime.Now.Year;
int month = DateTime.Now.Month;
int numDays = DateTime.DaysInMonth(year, month);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use DataTime.DaysInMonth()

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.daysinmonth(VS.71).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Remember to use the date they entered.
VB Code:

```
dim enteredDate as DateTime = cdate(txtDateBox.text)
dim daysInMonth as Int = DateTime.DaysInMonth(enteredDate.year,enteredDate.month)
```